# Проблема с версткой шапки

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, joomla3

index.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<header>
  <div id ="logo">
<a href="/"><img  src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/logo.png"></a>
  </div>
<div id="obertka-text1">
  <p class="head-text">
   asdsadasdasdadadadasdasdasdadsasdas
  </p>
</div>

</header>
```

css фаил:

```css
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

aside, footer, address, section, nav, header {
display:block;
}

img, iframe, video, embed {
max-width:100%!important;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
    src: local("HelveticaNeueCyr"),
    src: url(font/ofont_Helvetica Neue.ttf) format("truetype"); /* все современные браузеры */
    }




#page{
    background-image: url(../images/body.png);
    background-repeat: repeat ;
    width: 100%;

}

header{
  max-width: 1170px;
  max-height: 7.3em;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;


}
header #logo {
max-width: 83px;
max-height: 93px;
margin-top:0.5em;
margin-left:2rem;
overflow: hidden;
}
header #obertka-text1 {

  max-width: 550px;
  max-height: 2em;
float: left;
margin-left: 15%;
overflow: hidden;
}

header .head-text {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr", HelveticaNeueCyr,sans-serif;
   font-size:28px;

   color: #1d3857;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Вся проблема в том что блок с текстом прижался в низу.
Что я сделал не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неверно пользуетесь свойством `float`.

Добавьте `float: left;` для `#logo` и уберите `float` у `#obertka-text1`.

Подробнее про float: http://htmlbook.ru/css/float

Comment: Спасибо получилось.